# how to add sequence (auto increment) in apache ignite

Tags: ignite

Can anybody explain how to add auto increment on column using apache ignite web console?

What i've already done:

1) Configure->Configuration: Created Cluster Configuration

2) Configure->Configuration->My Cluster Configurations->**mytestcluster**->Advanced->SQL Scheme: I created here model with name testmodel:

Part from Domain model for SQL query:

```
<property name="keyFields">
    <list>
        <value>id</value>
        <value>date</value>
    </list>
</property>

<property name="fields">
    <map>
        <entry key="id" value="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
        <entry key="count" value="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
        <entry key="response" value="java.lang.String"/>
        <entry key="date" value="java.sql.Timestamp"/>       
    </map>
</property>

<property name="indexes">
    <list>
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryIndex">
            <property name="name" value="TESTMODELPK_NEW"/>
            <property name="indexType" value="SORTED"/>

            <property name="fields">
                <map>
                    <entry key="id" value="false"/>
                    <entry key="date" value="false"/>
                </map>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </list>
</property>
```

Now i need to have auto increment field ID.
No idea how to do it using Apache Ignite Web Console.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Ignite does not support Auto Increment fields yet.

Consider implementing Hi-Lo algorithm for allocating incrementing fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.